# jQuery dataTables 1.10.5 custom properties

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to set a custom property and be able to access/edit it later. Is this even possible, i've seen in older version one can use fnSettings but how do I use this in 1.10.5?

```
$('#table').DataTable({
        customProp: 'Hello World'
});
```

Then with a button click I thought I could do the following:

```
$('.test').on('click', function(e){
      var table = $('#table').DataTable();
      console.log(table.settings.oInit.customProp);
 }
```

However I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'customProp' of undefined

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `data()` method to store data in associated element. For example:

```
$('#table').data('customProp', 'Hello World');
```

Later you can retrieve it as shown below:

```
$('.test').on('click', function(e){
    console.log($('#table').data('customProp'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, `table.settings.oInit` is accessible upon initialisation only. After initialisation, neither `table.settings` nor `$("#table").DataTable().settings` holds `oInit` (or a function to access initialisation values). A workaround is to store `oInit` in a variable :

```
var init;

$('#example').DataTable({
   customProp: 'Hello World',
   initComplete: function(settings) { 
       init = settings.oInit;
   }
});
```

Now you can do this :

```
alert(init.customProp);
```

demo (1.10.5) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ajLe1484/**

Apparently dataTables passes one object in the callbacks, and a different somehow "cleaned up" object by the table instance. I am a little bit surprised dataTables does that. Tested it with 1.10.x too - the behaviour was the same, so it is not because `oInit` has been sunsetted by 1.10.5.

Answer (score 1):

For DataTables 1.10.10 and newer the following will work:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
        customProp: 'Hello World'
});

console.log($('#table').DataTable().init().customProp);
```